# How to dynamically name output of a sql file in sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, cmd, automation

**Objective:**

I would like to create a CSV dump on a weekly basis. I would like to name my file dynamically with the date.

The current code I have is:

```
sqlcmd -S INSTANCENAME -i c:\Users\name\Desktop\test.sql -o c:\Users\name\Desktop\name_$DYNAMIC$DATE.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
set timehour=%time:~0,2%
sqlcmd -S INSTANCENAME -i c:\Users\name\Desktop\test.sql -o c:\Users\name\Desktop\name-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%-%timehour: =0%%time:~3,2%.csv
```

You can try seeing the output by using Echo

```
set timehour=%time:~0,2%
echo name-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%-%timehour: =0%%time:~3,2%.csv
```

> %date% returns current date in short format. The ":~6,4" part is like a
>   SUBSTRING function which returns 4 characters starting from position
>   6, which returns Year. Similarly, retrieving month, day, hour,
>   minutes using same function and appending all of this together to
>   generate the file name in format "name-YYYYMMDD-HHMM"

Comment: This hardcoded process will not produce the desired result in other locales where the date and/or time format are different.

Comment: Hey @lit. Thanks for highlighting that.
You can use _'Setlocal'_ before sqlcmd. Final Query would be :
`setlocal`

`set timehour=%time:~0,2%`

`sqlcmd -S INSTANCENAME -i c:\Users\name\Desktop\test.sql -o c:\Users\name\Desktop\name-%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%-%timehour: =0%%time:~3,2%.csv`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell will let you control the formatting of the date. This removes any hardcoded dependence on a specific locale. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

I also replaced `name` with the standard `USERNAME` variable value.

```
FOR /F %A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd-HHmm'"') DO (SET "DYNAMICDATE=%A")
sqlcmd -S INSTANCENAME -i "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\test.sql" -o "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%USERNAME%_%DYNAMICDATE%.csv"
```